# What values to use for RIchEdit Ctrl?

Tags: winapi, formatting, character, richedit

ALL,

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787883%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

```
typedef struct _charformat2 {
  UINT     cbSize;
  DWORD    dwMask;
  DWORD    dwEffects;
  LONG     yHeight;
  LONG     yOffset;
  COLORREF crTextColor;
  BYTE     bCharSet;
  BYTE     bPitchAndFamily;
  TCHAR    szFaceName[LF_FACESIZE];
  WORD     wWeight;
  SHORT    sSpacing;
  COLORREF crBackColor;
  LCID     lcid;
#if (_RICHEDIT_VER >= 0x0500)
  union {
    DWORD dwReserved;
    DWORD dwCookie;
  };
#else 
  DWORD    dwReserved;
#endif 
  SHORT    sStyle;
  WORD     wKerning;
  BYTE     bUnderlineType;
  BYTE     bAnimation;
  BYTE     bRevAuthor;
#if (_RICHEDIT_VER >= 0x0800)
  BYTE     bUnderlineColor;
#endif 
} CHARFORMAT2;
```

The underline color is declared only for the control version >= 0x0800. However what should I do for the previous versions?

Also it looks like on Windows 8.1 this variable is not available. That is according to MSVC 2010.

So how do I make the bUnderlineType display the "red wave" underline and not use the standard black color?

Thank you.

[EDIT]
Sorry, I just recently found this contradiction in MSDN...
While [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787883.aspx) page says it is available in the RichEdit 4.1+, [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787873%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#_win32_Rich_Edit_Version_3.0) page says it is available in the RichEdit 3.0+. Now I know nobody cares about RichEdit 1.0, but a lot of systems are still using XP, whhich is 3.0, since MS Word does have the red squiggly underlining there.
Trouble is - while the underlinetype setting is pretty straightforward, the coloring of the underline on 3.0 is not.
Anybody have an idea of what to do?
[/EDIT]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1756263/how-to-change-underlining-color-in-a-rich-edit-control-win32-c

Comment: @edtheprogrammerguy, I tried the suggestion from the comment, i.e. "cf.bUnderlineType = CFU_UNDERLINEWAVE | 0x05;", but it does not work. I don't have use version 4 therefore I'm asking how to do it in versions 2 and 3. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

> So how do I make the bUnderlineType display the "red wave" underline and not use the standard black color?
>
> ....
>
> I don't have use version 4 therefore I'm asking how to do it in versions 2 and 3.

From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787883.aspx):

> **CFU_UNDERLINEWAVE**
>
> **RichEdit 4.1 and later**: Text underlined with a wavy line.

and

> ```
> #if (_RICHEDIT_VER >= 0x0800)
>   BYTE     bUnderlineColor;
> #endif
> ```

So the functionality that you are looking for does not exist in the old rich edit versions that you are targeting.

Comment: From another MSDN page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787873%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#_win32_Rich_Edit_Version_3.0, this functionality exists in version 3.0. Now while wave underline is straightforward, the coloring underline is not explained anywhere. And the undocumented code used in the comment does not work.